# Service Fabric Service HTTP/REST communication OWIN/Katana vs ASP.NET Core

Tags: http, owin, azure-service-fabric, katana, kestrel-http-server

I've got a stateless Service Fabric service that continiously performs some operations. I need to implement simple HTTP communication with it from client side.
I just need ability to turn it on/off and view if it is operating or not.

If I don't get it wrong, I've got two options here:

1) Implement Katana/OWIN self-host listener.

2) Use ASP.NET Core 2.0 with it's Kestrel server.

3) Use ASP.NET Core 2.0 with it's HTTP.sys server.
What is preferable option in terms of simplicity for such communication?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of simplicity I would go with the first option and implement it as an OWIN middleware, which you can later [use with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin#running-owin-middleware-in-the-aspnet-pipeline) if you change your mind.